# OWLOntology readOntology creates AnnotationProperty

Tags: java, owl, semantics, owl-api, turtle-rdf

I have to read an ontology, using OWLAPI; I use this JAVA code:

```
public class OwlApi {

public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, FileNotFoundException {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        File file = new File("myfile");
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(targetStream);      
}
}
```

My file is a simple turtle file, like this:

```
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix : <platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova> a owl:Ontology .

:proprietao a owl:ObjectProperty ;
rdfs:domain :classeuno ;
rdfs:range <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace> .

:proprietad a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
rdfs:domain <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace> ;
rdfs:range xsd:string .

:classeuno a owl:Class .
```

The outuput of loading the file is this one:

```
Ontology(OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova>) VersionIRI(<null>))) [Axioms: 7 Logical Axioms: 3] First 20 axioms: {DataPropertyRange(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietad> xsd:string) DataPropertyRange(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietao> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace>) Declaration(ObjectProperty(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietao>)) Declaration(DataProperty(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietad>)) Declaration(Class(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#classeuno>)) AnnotationPropertyDomain(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietad> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace>) ObjectPropertyDomain(<platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#proprietao> <platform:/resource/test/OWL/prova#classeuno>) }
```

I don't understand why is appearing a *AnnotationPropertyDomain* about the DataProperty.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace` is not declared as `owl:Class` and the parser is very strict. In OWL you have to type all entities explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're right! So if I have also to use owl:ObjectProperty or owl:DatatypeProperty from external ontology (like DBpedia) in my custom ontology, I have to declare that in the same way, right? What about ontology import, instead? Is sufficient to declare namespace and reuse class or properties from imported ontologies?

Comment: Yes, for each entity it's recommended to explicitly declare its type. If you import an ontology `A` it should be covered in `A` and therefore be sufficient to just "use" them in your ontology.